# Are there iPhone applications like INFOMAPS?

Tags: software-recommendation, applications

I am looking for iphone applications like [this one.](http://www.infomaps.nl/)

What I am looking is an app that:
Shows me the map, with tram stops and metro stops.
And with hotspots or touristic places in the map, so that you know where to getdown of the tram and metro.

This is the best one I used it already for amsterdam, but they dont have many cities.

Anyone knows apps like these, let me know

Answer (score -1):

Tomtom and Navigon do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Gtmort. Can you please add a link to the two apps you mention, as it is much more helpful to point the OP to the right software.